# Is there a way to change the latest version of a package on npm

Tags: npm, npm-publish

So for example, I made a package and published it with version `1.0.0`.

But then, I decided that I want to change the version of my package to `0.1.0`and add a default tag `latest`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the package.json, you need to update the version and then publish the package by using the attribute --tag=latest. So the syntaxt will become:
`npm publish --tag=latest`.